# Create YouTube video of graphic (e.g. album cover) with music (e.g. song from album)

Tags: windows, gratis, video, audio, youtube

I'd like to start posting some of my music on YouTube. My songs are in 192 Kbps MP3 format, and my album cover is a 600x600 JPEG image.

Are there any free applications for Windows that simply create a video for me to upload to YouTube?

GUI please, unless providing the exact command-line (*e.g.* ffmpeg) to produce the video I need.